# Compare Two pointer Arrays One of them from .h and one of them from cin

Tags: c++, pointers

I am newbie.
I have got a school project that there is a header file and it has got 82 usernames. Like

```
char *usernames[] ={a1,a2,a3,.... a82};
char *passwords[] =[p1,p2,...p82);
```

And I have finished large amount of my project but still I couldn't write an usefull code for login stage.
My code has to do take username and then asking for password.
For this stage I think basicly that loop:

```
char *usernamecheck;
char *passwordcheck;
cout<<"Please login. \n Username\n ";
cin >> usernamecheck ;
for(int flag=0;flag<82;flag++)
{
  if(usernamecheck==usernames[a]){
    passwordcheck==password[a];
  }
  else {
  }
}
cout<<"Please enter your password\n";
....
```

Then I will compare password taken from user and from header file.
I want to ask that point we didn't see that point on course. I have no idea how can I compare 2 char pointers. I tried to use as string but I have failed.

Comment: check strcmp, but as you are doing c++ then you can go for strings

Comment: `cin >> usernamecheck`  -- This right away will fail due to attempting to write to an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Three things: Trying to read into an uninitialized pointer, using 'a' is the index into the array when 'a' is not defined, using '==' rather than '=' to pull passwordcheck.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
char *usernamecheck;
...
cin >> usernamecheck ;
```

is going to be undefined behaviour. There is no memory associated with `usernamecheck`. You say:

> I tried to use as string but i have failed.

So dont use old archaic, methods when there are shiny new c++ ones available:

```
std::string usernamecheck;
...
cin >> usernamecheck;
bool isUser = usernamecheck == username;
```

Done.

use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), its the bomb.

[Live example.](http://ideone.com/JIhOvp)

Comment: So can i change my data.h file's code like ;
char *usernames = { ......} to string usernames = {.....}
and everything change to string ? so it will work :) i will try thank you so much